# Why do the math methods in my class return zero?

Tags: java, methods, return

I am new to Java and I am currently playing with methods and classes. I have made a small program for calculations, but my methods for multiplication and division is always returning zero. Here are the classes:

Operator class:

```
public class Operators {

    int add(int x, int y) {

        int sum;

        sum = x + y;

        return sum;

    }

    int sub(int x, int y) {

        int sum;

        sum = x - y;

        return sum;

    }

    int multiply(int x, int y) {

        int sum;

        sum = x * y;

        return sum;

    }

    int divide(int x, int y) {

        int sum;

        sum = x / y;

        return sum;

    }

    double sqrt(double x) {

        double sum;

        sum = Math.sqrt(x);

        return sum;

    }
}
```

Menu class:

```
public class Menu {

    Operators operator = new Operators();

    int a, b, addResult;
    int c, d, subResult;
    int e, f, mulResult;
    int g, h, divResult;
    double i, sqrResult;

    Scanner inndata = new Scanner(System.in);


    void chooseOperator(int what) {

        switch (what) {

        case '1' : 
            System.out.println("Type in the first number: ");
            a = inndata.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Type in the number you want to add: ");
            b = inndata.nextInt();

            addResult = operator.add(a,b);

            System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + addResult);
        break;

        case '2' : 
            System.out.println("Type in the first number: ");
            c = inndata.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Type in the number you want to subtract: ");
            d = inndata.nextInt();

            subResult = operator.sub(c,d);

            System.out.println(c + " - " + d + " = " + subResult);  
        break;

        case '3' : 
            System.out.println("Type in the first number: ");
            e = inndata.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Type in the number you want to multiply the first number with: ");
            f = inndata.nextInt();

            subResult = operator.multiply(e,f);

            System.out.println(e + " * " + f + " = " + mulResult);  
        break;

        case '4' : 
            System.out.println("Type in the first number: ");
            g = inndata.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Type in the number you want to dive the first number with: ");
            h = inndata.nextInt();

            subResult = operator.multiply(g,h);

            System.out.println(g + " / " + h + " = " + divResult);  
        break;

        case '5' : 
            System.out.println("Type in the number you want to square: ");
            i = inndata.nextInt();

            sqrResult = operator.sqrt(i);

            System.out.println("The square root of " + i + " is " + sqrResult);
        break;

        }       
    }

    void showMenu() {

        System.out.println("Choose operation:");
        System.out.println("    1. add");
        System.out.println("    2. subtract");
        System.out.println("    3. multiply");
        System.out.println("    4. divide");
        System.out.println("    5. square root");
        System.out.print("Choose one (q to quit): ");

    }

    boolean isValid(char ch) {

        if (ch < '1' || ch > '5' && ch != 'q' ) return true;
        else return false;

    }

}
```

The `println` command for both case 3 and 4 always shows that (e,f) and (g,h) are caught in the right way, but the math operation always returns 0. Can anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies with copy & paste.

Change:

```
subResult = operator.multiply(e,f);
```

to:

```
mulResult = operator.multiply(e,f);
```

Same for case 4:

```
divResult = operator.divide(g,h);
System.out.println(g + " / " + h + " = " + divResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case 4, you are still calling

```
operator.multiply(g,h);
```

I think you meant

```
operator.divide(g,h);
```

But - beware! Diving integers will always give an integer result, any decimal part in the 'real' answer will be truncated, e.g. 1/2 = 0, 3/2 = 1.